# Functions Calls Across Multiple C++ Source Files

Tags: c++, header-files, declaration, definition

I'm pretty new to using header files in c++ and I've been having a problem using a method in one source file that's defined in another. I've linked the sources files with a header file.

definition.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
int c::foo (int bar){

return bar;
}
```

function_call.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
int c::other_function( int num ){

int b = foo(num);

return b;
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

class c {

public:
int foo(int bar);
}

#endif /*HEADER_H_*/
```

I'm receving a compile error on my function_call.cpp:

```
error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
```

Did I overlook something?

Comment: I think your code bits are not real. If you would pass your code snippets to the compiler, then the first error would be very clean `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘foo’ with no type [-fpermissive]`. The next error would be `error: ; missing after class declaration`. To reach your quoted error, the code and includes must be different.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
class c {

public:
foo(int bar);
}
```

should be

```
class c {

public:
int foo(int bar);
}
```

You can not declare a function without explicitly set its return type.

To make your example work，you also need to declare `other_function` in `header.h` and have at least one`main`function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare the function prototype in the source file where you are including a class through header file, just after the including section.